# How the below recursion method works with argument enclosed with (i++,i)? can anyone explain?

Tags: c, recursion

```
void main()
{
    int x=1;
    reverse(x);
}

int reverse(int i)
{
    if(i>5)
    {
        return;
    }
    printf("%d",i);
    return reverse((i++,i));
}
```

output:

```
12345
```

How does the recursion call `reverse((i++,i))` map with `reverse(int i)`?

Comment: `return;` is invalid.

Comment: `(i++,i)` is `++i`

Comment: Your program has no output, because it does not compile: http://ideone.com/prctsY

Comment: Please copy/paste in the actual code you tested.

Answer (score 2):

`,` in `reverse((i++,i))` call is a comma operator. This call is equivalent to

```
i++;
return reverse(i);
```

---

Apart from this, signature `main` should be `int main(void)` and you should place a function prototype for the function `reverse` before `main`.

```
int reverse(int i);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your program does not compile since `return;` is invalid in a function that returns an `int`.
2. `(i++,i)` is equivalent to `++i`.